# How to subscribe on pulled out element from subscription when I do insert in meteor?

Tags: meteor, insert, subscription

For example I subscribe on myCollection with the limit = 10. And when I do: 
myCollection.insert({}), I don't want the first element from collection to be pulled out.

Comment: So you want 11 items after the insert?  If the items are sorted could you describe how?

Answer (score 0):

**From the Meteor docs**

> Cursors are a reactive data source. On the client, the first time you
>   retrieve a cursor's documents with fetch, map, or forEach inside a
>   reactive computation (eg, a template or autorun), Meteor will register
>   a dependency on the underlying data. Any change to the collection that
>   changes the documents in a cursor will trigger a recomputation. To
>   disable this behavior, pass {reactive: false} as an option to find.

[Is this what you need, disabling reactivity?](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)

`myCollection.find({}, {limit: 10, reactive: false});`